# Where can i find thee missing formulas in latest Nvidia CUDA Profiler user guide

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, nvprof

I found that in the previous version of profiler user guide, formula for the metrics are provided.

For example,

```
Metric Name: branch_efficiency
Description: Ratio of non-divergent branches to total branches
Formula: 100 * (branch - divergent_branch) / branch
```

But in the latest version, this "formula" part is replaced by "Scope". 
Do anyone know where can I find those formulas for latest profiler. Since nvprof add more features and metrics, I am not sure if I can still use the old version formula provided by nvprof v5.0 or previous.

Answer (score 1):

Since 5.5 `nvprof` can collect and report metric values similarly to events, so that you no longer have to calculate the metrics yourself.

Due to the complexity of some formulas, documentations since 5.5 no longer contain these formulas.

So to answer to question. No you cannot find it for the latest profiler. I think that the old formulas are still in place but there's no need for actually knowing the formulas anymore.

Source: [David Goodwin](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/542697/cuda-profiler-documentation-out-of-date/)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I think that nvprof doesn't directly collect the metrics. Those metrics are still derived from the events. Since i need to correlate the  metrics with hardware counter events, it is important for me to understand the formulas that nvprof used to calculate those metrics.